# Percentages in Instruments right in the blue line in Xcode 4

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode4, instruments

When I click on a row in the use of an object, in leaks or zombie for example, the lines are marked in blue...
and there are these percentages right in the line where reason of the leak/etc. should be.

[image: percentagenumberofinstruments]

But what does the percentage number mean?

I have sometimes trouble with understanding the percentages when there are like 5 of them with 15% and 25% and so on.

Comment: Are you releasing reihenfolge in dealloc?

Comment: The problem is not a leak or the code. I only want to know, what these percentages mean, independent from the code. Does it mean the chance that the leak is in ONLY one of these lines is 50%, or the leak is half in the one and half in the other line, or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the percentage of allocations that happened in your -init... method and where those allocations occurred. That's the instrument you're looking at and the method you drilled down into.

Comment: But I look at ONE Object of type __NSArrayM (think this mean one like NSMutable Array), what does the for loop has to do with with one allocation?

Comment: I'm not sure why it highlights the head of the for loop (vs. the one line within it), but you're adding things to the array there... so it needs to allocate more memory.